# What is it like to join between tables on different servers?

Tags: laravel, join

I have two db on different ip servers, one on localhost and the other on the server.
how do you join between tables?

```
$rka = \DB::connection('db_appel_shared');
    $rup_ut = $rka->table('m_rka_rev as a')
        ->select('*')
        ->join('vms_db.tbl_pejabat_pembelian2 as j', 'a.kode_unit', '=', 'j.id_unit') 
        ->join('vms_db.users as k', 'j.id_user', '=', 'k.id')
        ->where('j.id_user', Session::get('id'))
        ->get();
```

can you solve the problem, help me

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, where my app *can* have multiple databases for one, but i do not know, if it is so (customer can define the database).
So, i use the connection for my databases flexible.

In my `config/database.php` i defined a `main` connection and a `client` connection. Every model has a setting with `protected $connection = 'main'; // or "client"` and every time a customer comes in, i do check in `main` the configuration i have to set for `client` and then it works, regardless if the server is local or remote.

After this running, you can simply use the default `joins` from laravel without problems ;)

Hope, this will help you....